# I want to create a database using SQLiteOpenHelper but i am facing some problems

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a sub class (DatabaseHelper) of SQLiteOpenHelper Class.Its has a constructor and two overriden methods

```
 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, dbName, null,33);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ quizTable +"("+quizCol1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                quizCol2+" TEXT,"+ quizCol3 +" TEXT,"+ quizCol4 +" INTEGER," + quizCol5 + " DATETIME )");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ questionTable +"("+questionCol1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                questionCol2+" INTEGER,"+ questionCol3 +" TEXT,"+ questionCol4 +" TEXT," + questionCol5 + " TEXT," +
                questionCol6 + " TEXT," + questionCol7 +" TEXT," + questionCol8 +" TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ playedQuizzes +"("+playedQuizCol1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                playedQuizCol2+" TEXT,"+ playedQuizCol3 +" TEXT,"+ playedQuizCol4 +" TEXT," +
                playedQuizCol5 + " TEXT)");
        System.out.println("this is onCreate method");
        InsertQuiz();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+questionTable);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+playedQuizzes);

        onCreate(db);
    }
```

In my Activity subclass i have called the constructor of above class using

```
 public void onStart(){
        try{
            super.onStart();
             dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            CatchError(ex.toString());
        }       
    }
```

But when i run my Activity class and open my DDMS perspective then i did not find any database created under /data/data/

Is there something wrong with my knowlege or my code? If yes please tell me.

Comment: follow the link to clear your concepts about android database  http://hackaday.com/2010/07/21/android-development-101-part-3introduction-to-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) class:

> Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This
>   method always returns very quickly. The database is not actually
>   created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or
>   getReadableDatabase() is called.

So the database doesn't get created before not calling getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase().

Answer (score 1):

In your code you didn't open the database....

to create, write or open database `getWritableDatabase()`

or to create & open the database `getReadableDatabase()` is necessory.....